# Contacts are not displaying after Marshmallow update

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow

Recently I upgraded my Moto G (Second gen) to Android Marshmallow. After that, my Contacts app is not displaying any contacts and call logs. What I am getting is one blank screen only.

I tried installing other apps like Contacts+, True Dialer, etc. but the same result. In fact, Contacts+ is not launching only. It's getting stuck while launching. So, after the Marshmallow update, my phone is of no use, because I can't make any calls, see my call logs, etc.

Is this a bug with Marshmallow? Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could fix this issue by doing the following steps.

First Wipe the Cache partition. (It won't erase any files or settings)

To wipe the cache partition do the following steps.

1. Ensure the device is powered off, and unplugged
2. Press and hold the Volume Down button and Power button (located on the right edge of the device) for approximately 3 seconds then release.
3. From the "Boot Mode Selection Menu" screen, select Recovery.

   Note: Use the Volume Down button to scroll through the menu options        and the Volume Up button to select.
4. From the "No Command" screen (Android figure lying on his back), press and hold the Power button, tap Volume Up once and then release the Power button.
5. Select "wipe cache partition".
   Note: Use the Volume buttons to highlight and the Power button to select.
6. "Reboot system now" will be highlighted, press the Power button to select it.

   Note: Allow several minutes for the reboot process to complete.

Once you are done with the Wipe procedure , go to https://contacts.google.com and export your contacts as .vcf file and copy to your device.

Open Contacts App (Phone app) -> go to options on the top right corner (3 dots) -> choose import/export -> import from .vcf file. This will restore your contacts..

Comment: I tried wiping cache and it didn't seem to work (but it is possible that I simply didn't wait long enough for the contacts to re-appear) so I tried wiping the dalvik cache and that worked. (Just as a tip if someone is experiencing the same issue. Just wiping the cache, deleting the dalvik cache doesn't destroy any data on your phone)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Google account first, then set it up again. Go to the Contacts' setting & set contacts display as your Google account. This time, the sync will be as per the Google account and all invisible contacts not found during the search will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device's screen is on, then press & hold the Power button.
In the box that opens, touch & hold Power off.
You’ll see a “Reboot to safe mode” box. Touch OK.
Your device will start up in safe mode. go to contacts tab all contacts will update automatically then again reboot the device and you will be able to see the contacts in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your phone in safe mode, open the Contacts app, and you will see your contacts list loaded without any delay. Now switch off your phone and restart it in normal mode. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Moto G, the new Marshmallow doesn't allow to save contacts to phone accounts (device). You can save your phone numbers to your Google account and during the adding process of a new contact, there are no options to select the place where you actually want to save the new contact like it used to be in the previous version of Android; for instance -- SIM, phone, card, Google account.

In this way, Android tries to own you, your contacts, and all information about you.

Comment: To be fair, this depends on the Contacts app. Some 3rd-party Contacts apps still provide local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Press contact icon and drag it to app info.
Then go to permission and enable all options (storage).
Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Contacts - Contacts to Display.
Select All Contacts.

This worked on my Oppo R9 Plus with Android 6.